# The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading. when user idle for 10 minutes in asp.net page while fill the farm

Tags: asp.net, networking, session-state, iis-8

we deployed asp.net applications under two servers and users access this application using hostname and domain name, https://eservices.xxxx.com/eservice1/city.aspx

when they browse application the request goes to F5 and traffic divided to two asp.net webfront end servers.

when user  opens the page and  while he is filling the asp.net farm, when he idle for 5  to 10 Minutes, and after he save the button page can not displayed and showing the message in browse

secure connection failed

The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

Comment: Have you tried different browsers? I read about some issues like those on Firefox (37?).